# Java: Unit Test parallel execution of static methods (would run on multiple instances in production)

Tags: java, unit-testing, static-methods

I have a static method which creates unique IDs, based on a machine id and a counter. This essential would look something like this (without going into details about the actual algorithm):

```
public class Generator {
  static int counter = 0;
  static synchronized String generate(int machineId) {
    return generateID(counter++, machineId);
  } 
}
```

In production this would be fine as there would be no concurrent execution of this method per node. However, I would like to write a unit test which starts multiple threads in order to test if all generate IDs fulfill their requirements.

Obviously the problem now is the static method, which is great to work with, but prevents to test it that way, as the test is executed on a single machine only and the counter is shared between the threads.

Is there any way to trick the runtime to allow multiple instances of a static method within a unit test?

Comment: Why don't you change that into an instance method make `Generator` a singleton (if that must be) in production while creating multiple instance in your tests?

Comment: I don't like things that work different in tests than when I actually are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static fields exist for each runtime class. By using a dedicated class loader for each "machine" you want to simulate, you can give each "machine" dedicated runtime classes, which results in a static field per "machine".

Setting up these class loaders requires knowing where the class files (or JAR files) reside in the local file system, which may or may not be trivial to determine, depending on where the classes in question are ordinarily being loaded from.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's one of the answers where you question yourself "why didn't I actually think of that...". That link was quite helpful, in case anybody is trying to do something similar: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html#example

Comment: @meriton.  Assume i am using multithreading concept having single JVM, can multiple request on static method run parallely or it is automatically synchronized?